Configuring simple motion plan using moveit task constructor
I am trying to plan a simple path for my Fanuc CRX5ia robot using moveit task constructor pick and place tutorial as reference. My software:
Ubuntu 22.04
ROS2 Humble
I am getting error after error unfortunately.
Here is my code:
#include <rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp>
#include <moveit/planning_scene/planning_scene.h>
#include <moveit/planning_scene_interface/planning_scene_interface.h>
#include <moveit/task_constructor/task.h>
#include <moveit/task_constructor/solvers.h>
#include <moveit/task_constructor/stages.h>
#if __has_include(<tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.hpp>)
#include <tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.hpp>
#else
#include <tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.h>
#endif
#if __has_include(<tf2_eigen/tf2_eigen.hpp>)
#include <tf2_eigen/tf2_eigen.hpp>
#else
#include <tf2_eigen/tf2_eigen.h>
#endif

static const rclcpp::Logger LOGGER = rclcpp::get_logger("mtc_tutorial");
namespace mtc = moveit::task_constructor;

class MTCTaskNode
{
public:
  MTCTaskNode(const rclcpp::NodeOptions& options);

  rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeBaseInterface::SharedPtr getNodeBaseInterface();

  void doTask();

  void setupPlanningScene();

private:
  // Compose an MTC task from a series of stages.
  mtc::Task createTask();
  mtc::Task task_;
  rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr node_;
};

MTCTaskNode::MTCTaskNode(const rclcpp::NodeOptions& options)
  : node_{ std::make_shared<rclcpp::Node>("mtc_fanuc", options) }
{
}
rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeBaseInterface::SharedPtr MTCTaskNode::getNodeBaseInterface()
{
  return node_->get_node_base_interface();
}

void MTCTaskNode::setupPlanningScene()
{
  moveit_msgs::msg::CollisionObject object;
  object.id = "object";
  object.header.frame_id = "world";
  object.primitives.resize(1);
  object.primitives[0].type = shape_msgs::msg::SolidPrimitive::CYLINDER;
  object.primitives[0].dimensions = { 0.1, 0.02 };

  geometry_msgs::msg::Pose pose;
  pose.position.x = 0.5;
  pose.position.y = -0.25;
  pose.orientation.w = 1.0;
  object.pose = pose;

  moveit::planning_interface::PlanningSceneInterface psi;
  psi.applyCollisionObject(object);
}

void MTCTaskNode::doTask()
{
  task_ = createTask();

  try
  {
    task_.init();
  }
  catch (mtc::InitStageException& e)
  {
    RCLCPP_ERROR_STREAM(LOGGER, e);
    return;
  }

  if (!task_.plan(5 /* max_solutions */))
  {
    RCLCPP_ERROR_STREAM(LOGGER, "Task planning failed");
    return;
  }
  task_.introspection().publishSolution(*task_.solutions().front());

  auto result = task_.execute(*task_.solutions().front());
  if (result.val != moveit_msgs::msg::MoveItErrorCodes::SUCCESS)
  {
    RCLCPP_ERROR_STREAM(LOGGER, "Task execution failed");
    return;
  }

  return;
}

mtc::Task MTCTaskNode::createTask()
{
  mtc::Task task;
  task.stages()->setName("demo task");
  task.loadRobotModel(node_);

  const auto& arm_group_name = "arm";
  const auto& hand_group_name = "ee";
  const auto& hand_frame = "flange";

  // Set task properties
  task.setProperty("group", arm_group_name);
  task.setProperty("eef", hand_group_name);
  task.setProperty("ik_frame", hand_frame);

  mtc::Stage* current_state_ptr = nullptr;  // Forward current_state on to grasp pose generator
  auto stage_state_current = std::make_unique<mtc::stages::CurrentState>("current");
  current_state_ptr = stage_state_current.get();
  task.add(std::move(stage_state_current));

  auto sampling_planner = std::make_shared<mtc::solvers::PipelinePlanner>(node_);
  auto interpolation_planner = std::make_shared<mtc::solvers::JointInterpolationPlanner>();

  auto cartesian_planner = std::make_shared<mtc::solvers::CartesianPath>();
  cartesian_planner->setMaxVelocityScalingFactor(1.0);
  cartesian_planner->setMaxAccelerationScalingFactor(1.0);
  cartesian_planner->setStepSize(.01);

  // clang-format off
  auto stage_open_hand =
      std::make_unique<mtc::stages::MoveTo>("open hand", interpolation_planner);
  // clang-format on
  stage_open_hand->setGroup(hand_group_name);
  stage_open_hand->setGoal("open");
  task.add(std::move(stage_open_hand));

  // clang-format off
  auto stage_move_to_pick = std::make_unique<mtc::stages::Connect>(
      "move to pick",
      mtc::stages::Connect::GroupPlannerVector{ { arm_group_name, sampling_planner } });
  // clang-format on
  stage_move_to_pick->setTimeout(5.0);
  stage_move_to_pick->properties().configureInitFrom(mtc::Stage::PARENT);
  task.add(std::move(stage_move_to_pick));

  // clang-format off
  mtc::Stage* attach_object_stage =
      nullptr;  // Forward attach_object_stage to place pose generator
  // clang-format on

  // This is an example of SerialContainer usage. It's not strictly needed here.
  // In fact, `task` itself is a SerialContainer by default.
  {
    auto grasp = std::make_unique<mtc::SerialContainer>("pick object");
    task.properties().exposeTo(grasp->properties(), { "eef", "group", "ik_frame" });
    // clang-format off
    grasp->properties().configureInitFrom(mtc::Stage::PARENT,
                                          { "eef", "group", "ik_frame" });
    // clang-format on

    {
      // clang-format off
      auto stage =
          std::make_unique<mtc::stages::MoveRelative>("approach object", cartesian_planner);
      // clang-format on
      stage->properties().set("marker_ns", "approach_object");
      stage->properties().set("link", hand_frame);
      stage->properties().configureInitFrom(mtc::Stage::PARENT, { "group" });
      stage->setMinMaxDistance(0.1, 0.15);

      // Set hand forward direction
      geometry_msgs::msg::Vector3Stamped vec;
      vec.header.frame_id = hand_frame;
      vec.vector.z = 1.0;
      stage->setDirection(vec);
      grasp->insert(std::move(stage));
    }

    /****************************************************
  ---- *               Generate Grasp Pose                *
     ***************************************************/
    {
      // Sample grasp pose
      auto stage = std::make_unique<mtc::stages::GenerateGraspPose>("generate grasp pose");
      stage->properties().configureInitFrom(mtc::Stage::PARENT);
      stage->properties().set("marker_ns", "grasp_pose");
      stage->setPreGraspPose("open");
      stage->setObject("object");
      stage->setAngleDelta(M_PI / 12);
      stage->setMonitoredStage(current_state_ptr);  // Hook into current state

      // This is the transform from the object frame to the end-effector frame
      Eigen::Isometry3d grasp_frame_transform;
      Eigen::Quaterniond q = Eigen::AngleAxisd(M_PI / 2, Eigen::Vector3d::UnitX()) *
                             Eigen::AngleAxisd(M_PI / 2, Eigen::Vector3d::UnitY()) *
                             Eigen::AngleAxisd(M_PI / 2, Eigen::Vector3d::UnitZ());
      grasp_frame_transform.linear() = q.matrix();
      grasp_frame_transform.translation().z() = 0.1;

      // Compute IK
      // clang-format off
      auto wrapper =
          std::make_unique<mtc::stages::ComputeIK>("grasp pose IK", std::move(stage));
      // clang-format on
      wrapper->setMaxIKSolutions(8);
      wrapper->setMinSolutionDistance(1.0);
      wrapper->setIKFrame(grasp_frame_transform, hand_frame);
      wrapper->properties().configureInitFrom(mtc::Stage::PARENT, { "eef", "group" });
      wrapper->properties().configureInitFrom(mtc::Stage::INTERFACE, { "target_pose" });
      grasp->insert(std::move(wrapper));
    }

    {
      // clang-format off
      auto stage =
          std::make_unique<mtc::stages::ModifyPlanningScene>("allow collision (hand,object)");
      stage->allowCollisions("object",
                             task.getRobotModel()
                                 ->getJointModelGroup(hand_group_name)
                                 ->getLinkModelNamesWithCollisionGeometry(),
                             true);
      // clang-format on
      grasp->insert(std::move(stage));
    }

    {
      auto stage = std::make_unique<mtc::stages::MoveTo>("close hand", interpolation_planner);
      stage->setGroup(hand_group_name);
      stage->setGoal("yes");
      grasp->insert(std::move(stage));
    }

    {
      auto stage = std::make_unique<mtc::stages::ModifyPlanningScene>("attach object");
      stage->attachObject("object", hand_frame);
      attach_object_stage = stage.get();
      grasp->insert(std::move(stage));
    }

    {
      // clang-format off
      auto stage =
          std::make_unique<mtc::stages::MoveRelative>("lift object", cartesian_planner);
      // clang-format on
      stage->properties().configureInitFrom(mtc::Stage::PARENT, { "group" });
      stage->setMinMaxDistance(0.1, 0.3);
      stage->setIKFrame(hand_frame);
      stage->properties().set("marker_ns", "lift_object");

      // Set upward direction
      geometry_msgs::msg::Vector3Stamped vec;
      vec.header.frame_id = "world";
      vec.vector.z = 1.0;
      stage->setDirection(vec);
      grasp->insert(std::move(stage));
    }
    task.add(std::move(grasp));
  }

  {
    // clang-format off
    auto stage_move_to_place = std::make_unique<mtc::stages::Connect>(
        "move to place",
        mtc::stages::Connect::GroupPlannerVector{ { arm_group_name, sampling_planner },
                                                  { hand_group_name, interpolation_planner } });
    // clang-format on
    stage_move_to_place->setTimeout(5.0);
    stage_move_to_place->properties().configureInitFrom(mtc::Stage::PARENT);
    task.add(std::move(stage_move_to_place));
  }

  {
    auto place = std::make_unique<mtc::SerialContainer>("place object");
    task.properties().exposeTo(place->properties(), { "eef", "group", "ik_frame" });
    // clang-format off
    place->properties().configureInitFrom(mtc::Stage::PARENT,
                                          { "eef", "group", "ik_frame" });
    // clang-format on

    /****************************************************
  ---- *               Generate Place Pose                *
     ***************************************************/
    {
      // Sample place pose
      auto stage = std::make_unique<mtc::stages::GeneratePlacePose>("generate place pose");
      stage->properties().configureInitFrom(mtc::Stage::PARENT);
      stage->properties().set("marker_ns", "place_pose");
      stage->setObject("object");

      geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped target_pose_msg;
      target_pose_msg.header.frame_id = "object";
      target_pose_msg.pose.position.y = 0.5;
      target_pose_msg.pose.orientation.w = 1.0;
      stage->setPose(target_pose_msg);
      stage->setMonitoredStage(attach_object_stage);  // Hook into attach_object_stage

      // Compute IK
      // clang-format off
      auto wrapper =
          std::make_unique<mtc::stages::ComputeIK>("place pose IK", std::move(stage));
      // clang-format on
      wrapper->setMaxIKSolutions(2);
      wrapper->setMinSolutionDistance(1.0);
      wrapper->setIKFrame("object");
      wrapper->properties().configureInitFrom(mtc::Stage::PARENT, { "eef", "group" });
      wrapper->properties().configureInitFrom(mtc::Stage::INTERFACE, { "target_pose" });
      place->insert(std::move(wrapper));
    }

    {
      auto stage = std::make_unique<mtc::stages::MoveTo>("open hand", interpolation_planner);
      stage->setGroup(hand_group_name);
      stage->setGoal("open");
      place->insert(std::move(stage));
    }

    {
      // clang-format off
      auto stage =
          std::make_unique<mtc::stages::ModifyPlanningScene>("forbid collision (hand,object)");
      stage->allowCollisions("object",
                             task.getRobotModel()
                                 ->getJointModelGroup(hand_group_name)
                                 ->getLinkModelNamesWithCollisionGeometry(),
                             false);
      // clang-format on
      place->insert(std::move(stage));
    }

    {
      auto stage = std::make_unique<mtc::stages::ModifyPlanningScene>("detach object");
      stage->detachObject("object", hand_frame);
      place->insert(std::move(stage));
    }

    {
      auto stage = std::make_unique<mtc::stages::MoveRelative>("retreat", cartesian_planner);
      stage->properties().configureInitFrom(mtc::Stage::PARENT, { "group" });
      stage->setMinMaxDistance(0.1, 0.3);
      stage->setIKFrame(hand_frame);
      stage->properties().set("marker_ns", "retreat");

      // Set retreat direction
      geometry_msgs::msg::Vector3Stamped vec;
      vec.header.frame_id = "world";
      vec.vector.x = -0.5;
      stage->setDirection(vec);
      place->insert(std::move(stage));
    }
    task.add(std::move(place));
  }

  {
    auto stage = std::make_unique<mtc::stages::MoveTo>("return home", interpolation_planner);
    stage->properties().configureInitFrom(mtc::Stage::PARENT, { "group" });
    stage->setGoal("ready");
    task.add(std::move(stage));
  }
  return task;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);

  rclcpp::NodeOptions options;
  options.automatically_declare_parameters_from_overrides(true);

  auto mtc_task_node = std::make_shared<MTCTaskNode>(options);
  rclcpp::executors::MultiThreadedExecutor executor;

  auto spin_thread = std::make_unique<std::thread>([&executor, &mtc_task_node]() {
    executor.add_node(mtc_task_node->getNodeBaseInterface());
    executor.spin();
    executor.remove_node(mtc_task_node->getNodeBaseInterface());
  });

  mtc_task_node->setupPlanningScene();
  mtc_task_node->doTask();

  spin_thread->join();
  rclcpp::shutdown();
  return 0;
}

This is modified file from moveit pick&place with Task Constructor tutorial. The latest error I am getting is linked to this fragment:
  try
  {
    task_.init();
  }
  catch (mtc::InitStageException& e)
  {
    RCLCPP_ERROR_STREAM(LOGGER, e);
    return;
  }

So it seems like taks_.init() is failing but I have no idea why. Any help would be appreciated.
Also my launch file:
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from moveit_configs_utils import MoveItConfigsBuilder

def generate_launch_description():
    moveit_config = MoveItConfigsBuilder("crx5ia").to_dict()

    # MTC Demo node
    pick_place_demo = Node(
        package="mtc_tutorial",
        executable="mtc_fanuc",
        output="screen",
        parameters=[
            moveit_config,
        ],
    )

    return LaunchDescription([pick_place_demo])

And rviz launch file:
import os
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import ExecuteProcess
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from moveit_configs_utils import MoveItConfigsBuilder


def generate_launch_description():
    # planning_context
    moveit_config = (
        MoveItConfigsBuilder("crx5ia")
        .robot_description(file_path="config/crx5ia.urdf.xacro")
        .trajectory_execution(file_path="config/moveit_controllers.yaml")
        .to_moveit_configs()
    )

    # Load  ExecuteTaskSolutionCapability so we can execute found solutions in simulation
    move_group_capabilities = {
        "capabilities": "move_group/ExecuteTaskSolutionCapability"
    }

    # Start the actual move_group node/action server
    run_move_group_node = Node(
        package="moveit_ros_move_group",
        executable="move_group",
        output="screen",
        parameters=[
            moveit_config.to_dict(),
            move_group_capabilities,
        ],
    )

    # RViz
    rviz_config_file = (
        get_package_share_directory("crx5ia_moveit_config") + "/launch/mtc.rviz"
    )
    rviz_node = Node(
        package="rviz2",
        executable="rviz2",
        name="rviz2",
        output="log",
        arguments=["-d", rviz_config_file],
        parameters=[
            moveit_config.robot_description,
            moveit_config.robot_description_semantic,
        ],
    )

    # Static TF
    static_tf = Node(
        package="tf2_ros",
        executable="static_transform_publisher",
        name="static_transform_publisher",
        output="log",
        arguments=["0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "world", "base_link"],
    )

    # Publish TF
    robot_state_publisher = Node(
        package="robot_state_publisher",
        executable="robot_state_publisher",
        name="robot_state_publisher",
        output="both",
        parameters=[
            moveit_config.robot_description,
        ],
    )

    # ros2_control using FakeSystem as hardware
    ros2_controllers_path = os.path.join(
        get_package_share_directory("crx5ia_moveit_config"),
        "config",
        "ros2_controllers.yaml",
    )
    ros2_control_node = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="ros2_control_node",
        parameters=[moveit_config.to_dict(), ros2_controllers_path],
        output="both",
    )

    # Load controllers
    load_controllers = []
    for controller in [
        #"panda_arm_controller",
        #"panda_hand_controller",
        "joint_state_broadcaster",
    ]:
        load_controllers += [
            ExecuteProcess(
                cmd=["ros2 run controller_manager spawner {}".format(controller)],
                shell=True,
                output="screen",
            )
        ]

    return LaunchDescription(
        [
            rviz_node,
            static_tf,
            robot_state_publisher,
            run_move_group_node,
            ros2_control_node,
        ]
        + load_controllers
    )

And rviz config:
Panels:
  - Class: rviz_common/Displays
    Help Height: 78
    Name: Displays
    Property Tree Widget:
      Expanded:
        - /Global Options1
        - /Status1
        - /Motion Planning Tasks1
        - /PlanningScene1
      Splitter Ratio: 0.5
    Tree Height: 439
  - Class: rviz_common/Selection
    Name: Selection
  - Class: rviz_common/Tool Properties
    Expanded:
      - /2D Goal Pose1
      - /Publish Point1
    Name: Tool Properties
    Splitter Ratio: 0.5886790156364441
  - Class: rviz_common/Views
    Expanded:
      - /Current View1
    Name: Views
    Splitter Ratio: 0.5
  - Class: moveit_task_constructor/Motion Planning Tasks
    Global Settings:
      Task View Settings:
        Show Computation Times: true
        Task Expansion: All Expanded
    Name: Motion Planning Tasks
    Tasks View:
      property_splitter:
        - 197
        - 121
      solution_sorting:
        column: 0
        order: 1
      solutions_splitter:
        - 397
        - 198
      solutions_view_columns: ~
      tasks_view_columns:
        - 295
        - 26
        - 26
        - 48
Visualization Manager:
  Class: ""
  Displays:
    - Alpha: 0.5
      Cell Size: 1
      Class: rviz_default_plugins/Grid
      Color: 160; 160; 164
      Enabled: true
      Line Style:
        Line Width: 0.029999999329447746
        Value: Lines
      Name: Grid
      Normal Cell Count: 0
      Offset:
        X: 0
        Y: 0
        Z: 0
      Plane: XY
      Plane Cell Count: 10
      Reference Frame: <Fixed Frame>
      Value: true
    - Class: moveit_task_constructor/Motion Planning Tasks
      Enabled: true
      Interrupt Display: false
      Loop Animation: false
      Markers:
        All at once?: false
        Value: true
      Name: Motion Planning Tasks
      Robot:
        Fixed Robot Color: 150; 50; 150
        Robot Alpha: 0.5
        Show Robot Collision: false
        Show Robot Visual: true
        Use Fixed Robot Color: false
        Value: ""
      Robot Description: robot_description
      Scene:
        Attached Body Color: 150; 50; 150
        Scene Alpha: 0.8999999761581421
        Scene Color: 50; 230; 50
        Value: true
        Voxel Coloring: Z-Axis
        Voxel Rendering: Occupied Voxels
      Show Trail: false
      State Display Time: 0.05 s
      Task Solution Topic: /solution
      Tasks:
        Cartesian Path: 0
      Trail Step Size: 1
      Value: true
    - Class: moveit_rviz_plugin/PlanningScene
      Enabled: true
      Move Group Namespace: ""
      Name: PlanningScene
      Planning Scene Topic: /monitored_planning_scene
      Robot Description: robot_description
      Scene Geometry:
        Scene Alpha: 0.8999999761581421
        Scene Color: 50; 230; 50
        Scene Display Time: 0.009999999776482582
        Show Scene Geometry: true
        Voxel Coloring: Z-Axis
        Voxel Rendering: Occupied Voxels
      Scene Robot:
        Attached Body Color: 150; 50; 150
        Robot Alpha: 1
        Show Robot Collision: false
        Show Robot Visual: true
      Value: true
  Enabled: true
  Global Options:
    Background Color: 48; 48; 48
    Fixed Frame: base_link
    Frame Rate: 60
  Name: root
  Tools:
    - Class: rviz_default_plugins/Interact
      Hide Inactive Objects: true
    - Class: rviz_default_plugins/MoveCamera
    - Class: rviz_default_plugins/Select
    - Class: rviz_default_plugins/FocusCamera
    - Class: rviz_default_plugins/Measure
      Line color: 128; 128; 0
    - Class: rviz_default_plugins/SetInitialPose
      Topic:
        Depth: 5
        Durability Policy: Volatile
        History Policy: Keep Last
        Reliability Policy: Reliable
        Value: /initialpose
    - Class: rviz_default_plugins/SetGoal
      Topic:
        Depth: 5
        Durability Policy: Volatile
        History Policy: Keep Last
        Reliability Policy: Reliable
        Value: /goal_pose
    - Class: rviz_default_plugins/PublishPoint
      Single click: true
      Topic:
        Depth: 5
        Durability Policy: Volatile
        History Policy: Keep Last
        Reliability Policy: Reliable
        Value: /clicked_point
  Transformation:
    Current:
      Class: rviz_default_plugins/TF
  Value: true
  Views:
    Current:
      Class: rviz_default_plugins/Orbit
      Distance: 3.8008623123168945
      Enable Stereo Rendering:
        Stereo Eye Separation: 0.05999999865889549
        Stereo Focal Distance: 1
        Swap Stereo Eyes: false
        Value: false
      Focal Point:
        X: 0
        Y: 0
        Z: 0
      Focal Shape Fixed Size: true
      Focal Shape Size: 0.05000000074505806
      Invert Z Axis: false
      Name: Current View
      Near Clip Distance: 0.009999999776482582
      Pitch: 0.645397961139679
      Target Frame: <Fixed Frame>
      Value: Orbit (rviz)
      Yaw: 0.7453980445861816
    Saved: ~
Window Geometry:
  Displays:
    collapsed: false
  Height: 1043
  Hide Left Dock: false
  Hide Right Dock: false
  Motion Planning Tasks:
    collapsed: false
  Motion Planning Tasks - Slider:
    collapsed: false
  QMainWindow State: 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
  Selection:
    collapsed: false
  Tool Properties:
    collapsed: false
  Views:
    collapsed: false
  Width: 900
  X: 0
  Y: 0


I managed to find that task.init() function is responsible for initializing all stages with given scene. So it seems to be a problem with Planning Scene?
For convenience declaration of planning scene here:
void MTCTaskNode::setupPlanningScene()
{
  moveit_msgs::msg::CollisionObject object;
  object.id = "object";
  object.header.frame_id = "world";
  object.primitives.resize(1);
  object.primitives[0].type = shape_msgs::msg::SolidPrimitive::CYLINDER;
  object.primitives[0].dimensions = { 0.1, 0.02 };

  geometry_msgs::msg::Pose pose;
  pose.position.x = 0.5;
  pose.position.y = -0.25;
  pose.orientation.w = 1.0;
  object.pose = pose;

  moveit::planning_interface::PlanningSceneInterface psi;
  psi.applyCollisionObject(object);
}

The weird thing is, the cylinder is spawning in rviz
